# Codeigniter- Setting id of the other table be equal to id of another table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm stuck with setting the existing customers id be equal to the purchase id. This is model for entry.

On the else block, the error says:

> "Message: Object of class CI_DB_mysqli_result could not be converted
>   to string"

and error on this line: `"$purchase['cust_id'] = $cust;"`.

I'm a beginner in php and Codeigniter

```
    Class Entry_m extends CI_Controller{
    public function create_submit($customer, $purchase){

    $array = array('lname' => $customer['lname'], 'fname' => $customer['fname'], 'mn' => $customer['mn']);
    $this->db->like($array);
    $query = $this->db->get('customer');
    $count = $query->num_rows();
    if($count ===0)
    {
        $this->db->insert('customer', $customer);
        $cust_id = $this->db->insert_id();

        $purchase['cust_id'] = $cust_id;
        $this->db->insert('purchase', $purchase);
        return $cust_id = $this->db->insert_id();
    }else{
        $cust = $this->db->select('cust_id')->where($array)->get('customer');
        $purchase['cust_id'] = $cust;
        $this->db->insert('purchase', $purchase);   
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$cust = $this->db->select('cust_id')->where($array)->get('customer')->row()->cust_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead

```
    $this->db->insert('customer', $customer);
    $cust_id = $this->db->insert_id();
```

use

```
    $cust_id = $this->db->insert_id('customer', $customer);
```